# Проиграть звук перед закрытием страницы

Tags: javascript, html

Возможно ли при закрытии окна сайта чтобы сначала проигрывался звук, а затем страница закрывалась?

Comment: Вот код который работает в современных браузерах, который показывает сообщение при попытке закрыть страницу:
http://mattweb.ru/moj-blog/javascript-jquery/item/107-js-skript-podtverzhdenie-zakrytiya-stranitsy
Может его можно изменить?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно в таком варианте это сделать:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
event.returnValue = null;
document.getElementsByClassName('sound')[0].play();
};
```

только при этом когда начинает играть звук, появляется диалог, который спрашивает хочешь ли пользователь покинуть страницу

Comment: По какой-то причине alert не работает. Это должно работать в современных браузерах?
Или может я не так использую:
Пишу между <script> в <head>

Comment: alert не будет работать, для этого нужно возвратить текст
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
        var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
        e.returnValue = dialogText;
        return dialogText;
    };

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте более развёрнутый ответ. Ваш пример нужно дополнить кодом воспроизведения музыкальных файлов.

Comment: Как использовать не понимаю.
Делаю функцию воспроизведения soundplay().
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {  soundplay(); };
Так не работает